# LDAP dn syntax usage

Tags: php, syntax, ldap

This is my original syntax :

```
$dn = "OU=Users,OU=NA1,DC=corp,DC=pvt";
```

I want to add one more OU to `$dn`.

Directory structure is as below.
`OU=NA1`, there are 2 active directories under NA1 : Users and Contacts

So I would like to call both active directories in single line something like below. (Note: this syntax is not working)

```
$dn = "OU=Users+Contacts,OU=NA1,DC=corp,DC=pvt";
```

Is there any way to add both active directories in a single line?

Comment: What operation are you trying to perform, a search?

Answer (score 1):

For read operations, PHP supports a feature called parallel searches. This is not as simple as you might like, but you can achieve the results you want in a single operation.

```
$links = array($link, $link); // yes, two references to the same link

$DNs = array(
    'OU=Users,OU=NA1,DC=corp,DC=pvt',
    'OU=Contacts,OU=NA1,DC=corp,DC=pvt'
);

$filter = 'attr=val';

// a regular call to ldap_search()
// only now, $results is and array of result identifiers
$results = ldap_search($links, $DNs, $filter);
```

You can wrap this into a function that would make the call simpler, something like:

```
function ldap_multi_search($link, array $dns, $filter, array $attributes = null, $attrsonly = null, $sizelimit = null, $timelimit = null, $deref = null)
{
    $dns = array_values($dns);
    $links = array_fill(0, count($dns), $link);

    $results = ldap_search($links, $dns, $filter, $attributes, $attrsonly, $sizelimit, $timelimit, $deref);

    $retVal = array();
    foreach ($results as $i => $result) {
        if ($result === false) {
            trigger_error('LDAP search operation returned error for DN ' . $dns[$i], E_USER_WARNING);
            continue;
        }

        $entries = ldap_get_entries($result);
        unset($result['count']); // we'll calculate this properly at the end

        $retVal = array_merge($retVal, array_values($entries));
    }
    $entries['count'] = count($entries);

    return $entries;
}
```